# Can I download iOS 13 beta 6 simulator for Xcode 11 beta 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have the latest Xcode 11 beta 5 which includes iOS 13 beta 5 simulator. Today Apple released iOS 13 beta 6 but without releasing a new Xcode 11 beta.

Can I somehow download/update Xcode simulator to run iOS 13 beta 6 instead of beta 5? I currently don't wish to install the new beta on a real device so I'm totally relying on the simulator for testing. (I'm planning to install the final beta on real device later on).

Comment: Beta version simulators are bundled with beta version Xcode and can not be installed separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Among other reasons, the iOS 13 beta releases for devices are compiled to run on the CPUs in those devices, which are A-series ARM CPUs. The simulator runs on the CPU in your Mac, which is an x86 CPU. The simulator does not emulate the ARM instruction set.

Comment: I thought that maybe simulators that are running a newer beta than the Xcode bundled ones can be updated and be downloaded separately from Xcode.

Comment: You can go to Xcode > Preferences > Components > Simulators and click “Check and Install Now”. Mine didn't find any updates.